# Logical operators are not working in JS file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-addin, jquery, jsom

Everything is fine  I am able to fetching the data from SharePoint 2013 List using CAML query in my js file.
But when i try to get the data via dropdown conditions my code is executing in the else statement .Can aone help me what went wrong in my below code

```
 alert('entered into SVV function');
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
/*alert('Go Client Context');*/
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Execution');
var drbregionvalue= document.getElementById("drbregion").value;
var drbfunctionsvalue= document.getElementById("drbfunctions").value;
var drbmonthvalue=document.getElementById("drbmonth").value;
var allvalue="ALL";

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

if(drbfunctionsvalue!=allvalue && drbregionvalue!=allvalue)
{
alert('Your dropdown values for both are all');
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Region'/><Value Type='Text'>" + drbregionvalue + "</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + drbfunctionsvalue + "</Value></Eq></And></Where></Query></View>");
}
else
{
alert('Among 1 Dropdowns You selected all');

}
```

Comment: Try to put alert(drbfunctionsvalue) before if statement to see the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

It's not all that clear what your conditions are supposed to be, but based on the alert messages you have, these make the most sense to me.

```
if(drbfunctionsvalue==allvalue && drbregionvalue==allvalue) //AND => both
{
    alert('Your dropdown values for both are all');
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<...omitted...\>");
}
else if(drbfunctionsvalue==allvalue || drbregionvalue==allvalue) //OR => one
{
    alert('Among 1 Dropdowns You selected all');

}else{
    alert('Neither dropdown selected all');  //none selected all
}
```

Comment: Dear Paul / Martin,
                     Thanks for your support.Found the issue as I was getting the   dropdownlist default selected value.